# Distance attained in a space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, compactness

Consider the norm $\|(x,y)\|=|x|+|y|$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$. If $K$ is any non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$, I want to show that if $x\in \mathbb R^2$, then there exists $x_0\in K$ such that $\|x-x_0\|=d(x,K)$.

Since $\mathbb R^2$ is not compact we can't say that $K$ is compact. Then How to show?

I have taken the problem from Conway's "A Course in Abstract Analysis".

Comment: K = $\{\}$ ​ is a counterexample. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Sorry, $K$ should be non-empty.

Comment: Consider the closed disks $D_r = D(x, r) = \{ y \mid d(x, y) \le r\}$. What can you say about $D_s \cap K$ when $s = \inf \{ r \mid D(x, r) \cap K \neq \emptyset \}$?

Comment: Since $\mathbb R^2$ is finite dimensional, $D_s$ is compact and so $D_s\cap K$ being a closed subset of a compact space $D_s$ is compact.

Comment: If we define $f:D_s\cap K\to \mathbb R$ by $f(y)=\|x-y\|$ then $f$ being continuous there exists $x_0\in D_s\cap K\subset K$ such that $f(x_0)=\|x-x_0\|=\inf\{\|x-y\|:y\in D_s\cap K\}=d(x,D_s\cap K)=d(x,K)$.